# At the end of the slideshow go one up

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I have a very simple slideshow, but at the end it will go up. So it looks like a slotmachine. But that's not what i want. I'm not very experienced  in jQuery but i thinks i need an if statement.

But what is the simplest way? I'm trying to learn, so don't give me the direct answer :-)

```
function slideShow (){
var current = 1;
var start=1;
var top = 194;
var zero = 0;
var transition = 3000;

$.timer(transition*4, function (change) {
    switch(current){
        case 1:
            $(".slide").stop().animate({top: -top+"px"}, { duration: transition});
            current++;
        break;
        case 2:
            $(".slide").stop().animate({top: -top*2+"px"}, { duration: transition});
            current++;
        break;
        case 3:
            $(".slide").stop().animate({top: -top*3+"px"}, { duration: transition});
            current++;
        break;
        case 4:
        $(".slide").stop().animate({top: zero+"px"}, {duration: transition});
            current = start;
        break;  
        timer.reset();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reach **'case 4'**, you are setting the *'current'* variable to 1 again. So your slider starts back from **'case 1'**, resulting the slot machine effect.

Additionally, after your fourth switch, the timer.reset() code is unreachable because it's after the break.

Comment: Yes i got that, except for the timer.reset thing. But the thing i need to change is propably the top: -top to top: +top right?